# How to add custom features to Android soft keyboard

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

I'm working on a side project on native Android.
I want to add the feature in the picture attached to this post. I want to know how to achieve this feature in Android and what it's generally called.
Please help me.
Thanks.[Example of what I am intending to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlyne.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using a `FrameLayout` with `android:gravity="bottom"` and a nested `LinearLayout` or a `ConstraintLayout` with the suitable constraint and said `LinearLayout`.

**Example with `FrameLayout`**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:background="@color/lightGrey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <LinearLayout
        id="@+id/bottomToolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Btn"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Btn"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Btn"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Btn"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Result**
[image: result with framelayout]

**Example with `ConstraintLayout`**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/lightGrey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <LinearLayout
        id="@+id/bottomToolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Btn"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Btn"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Btn"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Btn"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result**

[image: result with constraint layout]

I've used buttons but you get the gist, you may use ImageButtons, Images, texts, whatever you please.

In addition to all of this you can also listen for they "Softkeyboard" appearing and disappearing and animate the `height` or visibility of the bottomToolbar so it looks extra cool. IE: when it appears show the bottom bar, when it disappears remove it.